# ShowDialog method is not working in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I added builDShowDialog method to run CircularProgressIndicator() until download the file.But it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
downloadFunction: () async{

          DialogBox.dialogBox(
              "Do you really want to download ${widget._uploadVideo.videoName.capitalize}${FirebaseApi.getExtension(widget._uploadVideo.videoUrl)}?"
              , context
              , () {
            if(isDownloading) return;
            setState(() {
              isDownloading =true;
            });

            isDownloading?
              buildShowDialog(context): null;
            print(isDownloading);

              downloadVideo(context,
                  widget._uploadVideo.videoUrl,
                  widget._uploadVideo.videoName).whenComplete(() => _buildDoneAnimation(context));

          });

        },
```

This is buildShowDialog method.

```
 buildShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
   return showDialog(
       context: context,
       barrierDismissible: false,
       builder: (BuildContext context) {
         return Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
       });
 }
```

Comment: I think downloading value getting true everytime. so that method terminated everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }
  )
```